# Event action of a specific label from an array of labels c#

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, events

I am working with an array of labels and I don't really know how to add a click action to all of them. For example if the user clicks on arrow[i] that arrow should display something. I've also searched on the internet and I haven't found anything useful.

Here is my code:

```
    Label[] _arr = new Label[4];
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++){

    _arr[i ] = new Label();
    _arr[i ].Text = ""+i;
    _arr[i ].Size = new Size(50,50);
    _arr[i ].Location = new Point(i*50,i*50);
    this.Controls.Add(_arr[i]);
}
```

}

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Yes, they are window forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 _arr[i] = new Label();   
 _arr[i].Click += (s, e) => MessageBox.Show("Message");
```

Comment: By the way, who are these variables(s and e ) ?

Comment: they are the sender and event objects.http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/aa645739(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 1):

When defining your label, include an event as such

```
_arr[i].Click += label1_Click;
```

Then if your using visual studio, you should get help creating the actual method by clicking tab at certain points during writing the above line. otherwise you need to make an event method your self such as

```
    void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //do stuff
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

_arr[i ].Click += delegate
                {
what you want to happend on click
                };